# Ajax call return fail using deferred objects / promises

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I just been frustrated with it for couple of hours, need some help from real expert.
In below code, I expect clicking on the button with class `fb_detail_btn` to be appended with the data result returned from .ajax function. However, what happened is that the previously non ajax appended data (`$(this).append("<div>aaaaaa</div>");`) will always be erased once the ajax run. **My test shows the php file has run correctly so the problem is why ajax returned data is not able to be appened to $(this) which assigned as a variable.**

JavaScript

```
//GET FEEDBACK DETAIL METHOD//
function get_feeback_detail(result) {
    alert('inside get_feeback_detail, btn_clicked_id is '+btn_clicked_id);
    return $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../x_get/get_feedback_detail.php",
        data:{fb_id: btn_clicked_id},
    }).then(function(data) {
                alert('then ran!');
                //loading_effect_hide();
                var dataSplit = data.split("|");
                commCode = dataSplit[0];
                //alert(dataSplit[1]);
                if(commCode !=1){
                    $('#testInfo').html(dataSplit[1]);
                    $('#testInfo').addClass("errorRed");
                    //$('.fb_review_table_section').empty();
                    alert('returned false for then in ajax!');
                    return false;
                }else{
                    result =dataSplit[1];
                }   
                alert('result inside then is...   '+result);
                //alert(selectedDiv.attr('class'));
                //return result;
                selectedDiv.append(result);
            //loading_effect_hide();    

    }).fail(function(x,s,e) {
            alert(s+": "+e);
            alert('detail button failed!');// an error occurred

            //alert(result);
        });//$.ajax END

    alert('inside get_feeback_detail, result is...   '+result);


};//get_feeback_detail() END



//Detail Button
$(document).on('click','.fb_detail_btn',function(){
    selectedDiv=$(this);
    selectedDiv.append("<div>aaaaaa</div>");
    elementPropertyName = selectedDiv.attr('name');
    btnNames = $(this).attr("name").split("_");
    btn_clicked_id=btnNames[1];
    result="";
    get_feeback_detail();
    selectedDiv.append("<div>bbbbbbb</div>");
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="fb_detail_btn" name="detail_68">aaadadadadadad</div>
```

**=Update=
Currently, the result of the work will reach .then but result will not be appended.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @Bergi, I came up my solution actually was inspired by the post you referred, but I do not think I used it correctly. If you could, help me on fixing this speicifc problem will be appreciated

Comment: Then use `.fail(function(x,s,e){alert(s+": "+e);})` to see *why* it's failing not only *that* it's failing. Probably your server is not responding as expected, use the network inspector in your devtools.

Comment: @Bergi, the new updated version works, but still, result can not be appended

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing promises.

You need to return your new result from a `then()` callback:

```
    return $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../x_get/get_feedback_detail.php",
        data: 'fb_id='+btn_clicked_id,
        dataType:'json',//ACW-soemthing new!
    }).then(function(data) {
        ...
        return result;
    });
```

Comment: I am a bit confused on when to accept the btn_clicked_id as a variable for ajax in get_feeback_detail but after the result is returned from the function get_feeback_detail, where should I put the returned result? as btn_clicked_id ? I am confused...

Comment: @Chen: You should not be calling `ajaxComplete`.  The `then()` callback runs after you get the response, and you need to return your transformed value directly from it.

Comment: I just updated again, fixed fail issue, but still, its can not be appended while data appearantly there. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in more detail,my work do take the string, but it will not load into corosponding cell. Thanks!

Comment: @Chen: Use the debugger to find the problem.

Comment: but the problem is that NO errors return for the Chrome Inspector

Comment: @Chen: Use the **debugger** (Scripts tab) to see what your variables are.

Answer (score 0):

This code cannot work:

> ```
> return $.ajax ({
>     …
> }).then(function(data) {
>     … // callback
>     return result;
> }); //$.ajax END
>
> alert('inside get_feeback_detail, result is...   '+result);
> selectedDiv.append(result);
> ```

**A**jax is *asynchronous*! As you see in the alert, the result is `undefined` when that part runs. It is available only in the callback! Read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call), and use

```
return $.ajax ({
    …
}).then(function(data) {
    … // callback
    // return result; 
    alert('inside ajax callback, result is...   '+result);
    selectedDiv.append(result); // works now!
});
```

Comment: I fixed code according to your method, but I am more confused now. Do you mean to run selectedDiv.append(result); inside .then and take out return result? I tried it and updated code, its not working still

Comment: Could you assist me find the error in the code? I did many hours yesterday, I still can't find why.

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I suggested.

Comment: did you tried to actually execute the code? I tried your solution, it did not work...

Comment: Of course I didn't try it, I don't know what your `data` is. If you don't tell me *what* did not work, I cannot help you…